# How to read a file in Spark (with scala) using new File()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a begginer about spark and I have a question for you.
I want to read a file. I see some tutorial and they say to do that :

```
val rib = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("<a path to the file>")
```

However (like I'm curious ;) ), I tried to do this classic line (that I used before in a scala program) :

```
val file:File = new File("<same path>").
```

The first line works (I can see the datas with show()) but the second says that the file doesn't exist. However, this is the same path.

If anyone can telln me why?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Probably the file is not in the normal filesystem but in some kind of distributed file system like **HDFS** or **S3**. Also, even if the file would exist for a local development in production it would never be in a normal file system neither it should fit in the main memory of just one program. Also the first one gives you a better abstraction, it directly creates a `DataFrame` _(distribute the data)_ for you, handles schema discovery, is capable of parse multiple formats like CSV or JSON, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So quite often when having Spark as part of a Hadoop stack the default Filesystem that Sparks uses is actually HDFS. The default FileSystem for Spark can be configured IIRC.

`new File` however would reference your local filesystem (most likely that of the driver specifically). That would mean that your code and work doesn't get distributed but is all done locally.

Comment: Therefore, if I good understand, new File () , doesn't work because it can't distributes the task whereas spark.read.load can ?

Comment: well so the problem why it doesnt *work* is most likely that spark accesses a different file systems. however even if it would work you'd have the issue that your work wouldn't be distributed. you'd de-facto just write a regular scala program with a useless spark dependency ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, I think that I begin to understand; it wouldn't be distributed because the other fileSystem hasn't my file ? But why the function load succed to open the file in this case ?

Comment: so `spark.read.csv("/data/asdf")` referes to some file/folder /data/asdf located on sparks configured default file system which most likely is a HDFS meaning that file is effectively distributed over several physical machienes. `new File("/home/me"` referes to "/home/me" located on the local file system of the computer executing that code.

Comment: Ok thanks I see the difference. read search in the default file system and this file system can be distant. That's why it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dominic for your answers.